Sound not working after clean Parrot OS Upgrade
I just installed Parrot OS and updated it to the latest software but I'm having trouble getting the sound to work.  I could previously see a graphical representation of sound in the volume bar, but since playing around with it, that has gone now too.
I have pipewire installed as well as alsa.  I tried fiddling around in qpwgraph but it doesn't seem to let me join sound to the playback devices!
Here is the output of relative information...
$aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 7: HDMI 1 [HDMI 1]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 8: HDMI 2 [HDMI 2]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: NVidia [HDA NVidia], device 9: HDMI 3 [HDMI 3]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: Mic [Samson Go Mic], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0

$lspci | grep -i audio

00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation TU106 High Definition Audio Controller (rev a1)

$systemctl --user status pulseaudio 
Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found.


$systemctl --user status pipewire pipewire-pulseaudio 
Unit pipewire-pulseaudio.service could not be found.
● pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service; enabled; preset: enabled)
    Drop-In: /usr/lib/systemd/user/pipewire.service.d
             └─parrot.conf
     Active: active (running) since Fri 2024-11-01 09:35:22 GMT; 18min ago
TriggeredBy: ● pipewire.socket
   Main PID: 1684 (pipewire)
      Tasks: 2 (limit: 37619)
     Memory: 49.1M
        CPU: 573ms
     CGroup: /user.slice/user-1000.slice/user@1000.service/session.slice/pipewire.service
             └─1684 /usr/bin/pipewire

Nov 01 09:35:22 xxx systemd[1665]: Started pipewire.service - PipeWire Multimedia Service.
Nov 01 09:35:22 xxx pipewire[1684]: mod.rt: Can't find org.freedesktop.portal.Desktop. Is xdg-desk>
Nov 01 09:35:22 xxx pipewire[1684]: mod.rt: found session bus but no portal


$systemctl --user status pipewire-alsa
Unit pipewire-alsa.service could not be found.

$sudo inxi -ACSxxz

System:
  Kernel: 6.10.11-amd64 arch: x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 12.2.0
  Desktop: KDE Plasma v: 5.27.5 Distro: Parrot Security 6.2 (lorikeet) lory
    base: Debian squeeze
CPU:
  Info: 6-core model: Intel Core i7-9850H bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Coffee Lake rev: D cache: L1: 384 KiB L2: 1.5 MiB L3: 12 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 800 min/max: 800/4600 cores: 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800
    5: 800 6: 800 7: 800 8: 800 9: 800 10: 800 11: 800 12: 800 bogomips: 62431
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630] vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: i915 v: kernel arch: Gen-9.5 bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106GLM [Quadro RTX 3000 Mobile / Max-Q]
    vendor: Hewlett-Packard driver: nouveau v: kernel arch: Turing
    bus-ID: 01:00.0 temp: 19.0 C
  Device-3: Cheng Uei Precision Industry (Foxlink) HP Wide Vision HD
    Integrated Webcam driver: uvcvideo type: USB bus-ID: 1-7:5
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.7 with: Xwayland v: 22.1.9 driver: X:
    loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa dri: iris gpu: i915
    resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz
  API: EGL v: 1.5 drivers: iris,nouveau,swrast platforms:
    active: gbm,x11,surfaceless,device inactive: wayland
  API: OpenGL v: 4.6 vendor: intel mesa v: 24.2.4-1~bpo12+1 glx-v: 1.4
    direct-render: yes renderer: Mesa Intel UHD Graphics 630 (CFL GT2)
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: sof-audio-pci-intel-cnl bus-ID: 00:1f.3 chip-ID: 8086:a348
  Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor: Hewlett-Packard
    driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel pcie: speed: 8 GT/s lanes: 16
    bus-ID: 01:00.1 chip-ID: 10de:10f9
  Device-3: Samson GoMic compact condenser mic
    driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio,usbhid type: USB rev: 1.1 speed: 12 Mb/s
    lanes: 1 bus-ID: 1-1.4:6 chip-ID: 17a0:0305
  API: ALSA v: k6.10.11-amd64 status: kernel-api
  Server-1: PipeWire v: 0.3.65 status: n/a (root, process) with:
    1: pipewire-pulse status: active 2: wireplumber status: active
    3: pipewire-alsa type: plugin
Repos:
  Packages: 2621
  No active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/debian.list
    1: deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ testing main contrib non-free
    2: deb http://security.debian.org/ testing-security main contrib non-free
    3: deb http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian/ unstable main contrib non-free
  Active apt repos in: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/parrot.list
    1: deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
    2: deb https://deb.parrot.sh/direct/parrot lory-security main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
    3: deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory-backports main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
    4: deb https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory-updates main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
Info:
  Processes: 314 Uptime: 24m Init: systemd target: graphical (5)
  Compilers: gcc: 12.2.0 Shell: Bash v: 5.2.15 inxi: 3.3.36

$LANG=C aplay -L | grep -A 1 default
default
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
--
sysdefault:CARD=Mic
    Samson Go Mic, USB Audio

$cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [NVidia         ]: HDA-Intel - HDA NVidia
                      HDA NVidia at 0xe6000000 irq 17
 1 [Mic            ]: USB-Audio - Samson Go Mic
                      Samson Technologies Samson Go Mic at usb-0000:00:14.0-1.4, full speed

$cat /proc/asound/version
Advanced Linux Sound Architecture Driver Version k6.10.11-amd64.

$cat /proc/asound/card*/codec* | grep Codec
Codec: Nvidia GPU 93 HDMI/DP

$apt policy alsa-ucm-conf
alsa-ucm-conf:
  Installed: 1.2.8-1
  Candidate: 1.2.8-1
  Version table:
     1.2.12-1 540
        540 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
        540 http://ftp.uk.debian.org/debian unstable/main amd64 Packages
 *** 1.2.8-1 600
        600 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory/main amd64 Packages
        598 https://deb.parrot.sh/parrot lory-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

Let me know if you need anymore info...
Other things I have done:
Added blacklist snd_hda_intel to '/etc/modprobe/alsa-base.conf'. Pulled the absolute latest alsa-ucm2-frimware from github and dropped it into '/usr/share/alsa/ucm2'. Added my user to the audio group. Added :
pcm.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

ctl.!default {
    type hw
    card 0
}

to '/etc/asound.conf'
Notable comments :
I'm not sure if adding blacklist snd_hda_intel to '/etc/modprobe/alsa-base.conf' does anything as 'modprobe/alsa-base.conf' didn't exist.
Not sure if this is conflicting things ;
$LANG=C aplay -L | grep -A 1 default
default
hw:CARD=NVidia,DEV=3
--
sysdefault:CARD=Mic
    Samson Go Mic, USB Audio

, since I set the Nvidia as Default.  But perhaps I need 00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10) to be a playback device, but it doesn't seem to appear anywhere.  Do I need to install snd_hda_intel?
I've spent far too long trying to solve this, be grateful to get some help...  Thanks in advance.

Are your sound devices muted? Run alsamixer, select the proper output device, and look for a Green M.  If there are Green M's unmute them by pressing the Up Arrow.

I don't think so.  I have green '00's but they didn't change by using the 'UP Arrow' or numbers...

Green 100's on everything?

No, just "00", it won't let me change them...

Press M to unmute or the up arrow on your keyboard to unmute/turn up. 00 is on but silent.

That was the first thing I tried.  Look at my first comment.  Can anyone check my issue and see what else could be the issue?

Why have you blacklisted the driver for Device 3 snd-hda-intel when aplay lists it as the default device? See here.  If you want to use Device-1: Intel Cannon Lake PCH cAVS vendor: Hewlett-Packard you need to change the default output device from 3 to 1, and use the green plug on the back of your Motherboard.

I'm not in front of my Linux install right now but if I remember correctly running alsamixer and pressing F6 allows you to choose the default.  I'll update this comment when I get home tonight.

I just want to get the internal speakers working.  My previous install that became corrupted worked using Parrot OS, which is what I have installed now.  The sound quality wasn't very good and I did have problems that I got around by using $qpwgraph but that doesn't appear to be able to link sound to the output.

I would like to use the best driver available, which I guess is for Device-2: NVIDIA TU106 High Definition Audio vendor, so far I can only get audio through headphones using my Samson Technologies Samson Go Mic

You need to remove snd-hda-intel from the blacklist as that is the NVIDIA driver.  You then need to mute or blacklist Device 3: driver: hid-generic,snd-usb-audio, then reboot.

Here is my alsa-base.conf ```
#blacklist snd_hda_intel /n
blacklist hid-generic, snd-usb-audio /n
options snd-hda-intel model=generic


If you create a Ubuntu Live USB and boot with that does it work?  I'm trying to rule out your config or the kernel here.
